# Django model saving twice.. why?

Tags: django, django-models

I have an ajax call within a function

```
console.log("Executing call on " + link);

$.ajax({
  type : "POST",
  url : link,
  data : {"clientId" : selectedClient, "id" : id},
  dataType : "json",
  success : function(retData) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(retData));
  } 
})
```

that calls in views.py:

```
def putClientPeerData(request):
  client = Client.objects.get(client = request.REQUEST["clientId"])
  peer = Client.objects.get(client = request.REQUEST["id"])
  ClientPeers.objects.create(client = client, parentorg = peer.parentorg, eff_date = datetime.now(), exp_date = None).save()
  testPeer = ClientPeers.objects.get(client = client, parentorg = peer.parentorg)

  if testPeer.client == client:
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({"returnValue" : "success"}))
  else:
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({"returnValue" : "failure"}))
```

However, the `save` method executes twice, which results in a `MultipleObjectsReturned` exception on the `testPeer` query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`create` calls `save`, there's no need to call it explicitly.

---

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#create):

*`create(**kwargs)`*

A convenience method for creating an object and saving it all in one step. Thus:

```
p = Person.objects.create(first_name="Bruce", last_name="Springsteen")
```

and:

```
p = Person(first_name="Bruce", last_name="Springsteen")
p.save(force_insert=True)
```

are equivalent.